# How can I make passwords really visible?

Tags: password, 6.0-marshmallow

I've got a Nexus 7 running Android 6.0.  I'd like to set a PIN for the lock screen, but given the inaccuracy of touchscreen keyboards, I'm not comfortable creating a password when I can't see what I'm typing.

Is there a way to disable password hiding?  I've found the "make passwords visible" setting, but that only makes the most-recently-typed character visible -- worthless if you've fumbled and typed two characters at once.

Comment: Afraid not. But when setting up a pin/password, you've got to enter it twice – exactly for this reason: if you've "fumbled" and got it wrong the first time, you'd need to repeat the very same mistake – or the password won't be accepted (i.e. no changes applied).

Comment: You can make a pattern passcode. This will exclude "type fumbling".